# What is the best term I can use to describe a distributed programming team

Tags: team, telecommute, workload

I have worked on several programming teams in which I was Georgia, my boss was in New York, the design team was in California, etc.  We all communicated via phone, a job ticket system and Skype.  Most of us were independent contractors, who contracted for and out-sourced to various other team members (seriously, the scheme of who-paid-who was a little crazy.)

What is the best term that I can use to describe this setup which I can use to talk about my work history?  Could it be:

Distributed programming team,
Remote Distributed team,

This work experience is becoming more common and I would like to say that I have had this kind of work experience.  However, if I use an incorrect term (like SRCUM) I will sound ridiculous, and I will lose credibility.

Comment: Describe to whom? Is this for your resume? Interview? LinkedIn profile?

Comment: I was hoping that a good term could be used universally.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "name that thing" question. "Name that thing" are bad questions for the same reasons that "identify this obscure TV show, film or book by its characters or story" are bad questions: you can't Google them, they aren't practical in any way, they don't help anyone else, and allowing them opens the door for the asking of other types of marginal questions. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game

Comment: It is my hope to sound more professional when I refer to an experience that is growing more common.  I feel that this is not just a 'name that thing' question but one that will help me not sound ridiculous as I talk to other professionals.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology

Comment: if you want _a good term that could be used universally_. simply "Developer" would be nice

Comment: Questions that poll for opinions aren't really what we do on Stack Exchange. Instead, problems like this work out a lot better in [chat], which works a lot better for discussion-oriented issues. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Geographically distributed programming team" is probably fine; just a bit clearer for folks who haven't worked in such a group, while retaining the most common phrase I've heard for describing this arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a single term for your situation, so my answer is none.

You were a contractor, working with a distributed team, but you did not work in an office (Worked from home/unsupervised?). Sort of a contractor working remotely with a distributed team. There's three parts to your experience in this situation.

Comment: I worked in a variety of locations, including the main office.  The work was not always directly supervised unless the task was a difficult one.  The final products were website for musicians.